# User input that matches a Dataframe value

Tags: python, datetime, user-input

I'm trying to get a User's date input based on a certain format (e.g. MM/YYYY) and I wanted it to loop until the User provides an input that is in the right format and within the date range of the data set.

I've tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work as I have intended.
Sorry, i'm new to Python and i'm not sure how I should amend the code to my desired outcome.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as  np

date_rng = pd.date_range(start = '1/12/2016', end='01/08/2019', freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['Date'])
df['Col1'] = np.random.randn(len(df['Date']))
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')

is_Valid = False
while not is_Valid:
    start_dt = input('Input start date between ' + df.iloc[0,0] + ' & '  + df.iloc[-1,0])
    try:
        ui = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_dt,'%m/%Y')
        is_Valid = True
        for dts in df['Date']:
            if start_dt == dts:
                print('OKAY')
            else:
                start_dt = input('Out of Range. Try Again.')
    except:
        print('Wrong Format. Try again')
```

Comment: What is the behaviour you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were almost there just check out a small tweak. Datetime objects can be compared logically to a range. Of course if you want it to keep looping you might want to reset is_Valid flag

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as  np

date_rng = pd.date_range(start = '1/12/2016', end='01/08/2019', freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['Date'])
df['Col1'] = np.random.randn(len(df['Date']))
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')

is_Valid = False
while not is_Valid:
    start_dt = input('Input start date between ' + df.iloc[0,0] + ' & '  + df.iloc[-1,0] + ' -  :')
    try:
        ui = dt.datetime.strptime(start_dt,'%m/%Y')
        is_Valid = True
        if (ui<=max(date_rng)) & (ui>=min(date_rng)):
            print("Okay")
        else:
            start_dt = input('Out of Range. Try Again.')
            is_Valid = False
    except:
        print('Wrong Format. Try again')
        is_Valid = False
```